# Display if a post has been flagged already

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags

If a post has already been flagged by a different user, there is no point in another user flagging it. In my opinion, it's a waste of flags that could be used to flag other low quality posts. But currently, there is no way to find out if a post has already been flagged by just looking at it.

Is it possible to either:

- disable the flag link, so no other user can flag it, or
- add a number of times the post has been flagged (similar to close votes), to leave it upto the user to flag or not to flag?

Comment: Do flags on the same question actually add any clutter? I know that in some situations like this it's deliberately hidden to avoid band-waggonning

Comment: I'm not too sure about the clutter but what's the point of using up your flags on something that has already been flagged by someone else?

Comment: Why is there no point? An additional flag could identify another issue or confirm a problem from a previous flag, and the additional flag will bump it up higher into the queue so it can be acted upon faster. Extra VLQ or NAA flags will require more Looks Good responses in the LQP queue... There are lots of benefits. It's certainly not pointless.

Comment: @animuson Right, that "bump it higher" bit is probably the knowledge that was missing, otherwise it pretty well will be a waste of a flag (assuming it's the same type of flag of course)

Comment: @animuson: Apologies about the choice of words, what I meant was that in my opinion, a user should at least be able to see if a post has already been flagged and then make a choice to either flag or not.

Comment: Re. "Why the downvote with no comment?" [Voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), often used to signal agreement/disagreement, especially on feature requests. Don't take it personally, it doesn't necessarily mean that there's something wrong with your post, it could just be that others disagree with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This information is not supposed to be relevant to users. Whenever you see a problem that warrants review or moderator attention, you should flag it, *regardless of whether it has been seen or flagged by anyone else*. A problem is a problem as long as it has not been handled.

As mentioned, the number of flags against a post has several tangible effects on its position in the review queue (and the number or weight of review actions taken against it) as well as the moderator queue. If a user were to choose to abstain from flagging a post simply because it has already been flagged by at least one other user, this could result in more incorrect reviews given the pass, or in the case of moderator flags, pressing issues that could be pushed away by less important issues (or, even worse, *non-issues*).

Comment: Well said; I agree.